# SELECT CASE with inner SELECT

Tags: sql, case

I need to create a SQL with SELECT CASE, and what I need to do is, if an inner SELECT returns more than one element, I need to execute the overall SELECT, otherwise to return empty string. The code that works is something like this (paraphrased):

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT obj.param1 WHERE...) 
          from table1) > 1 THEN '' 
    ELSE SELECT * from table2 
   where obj2.param1 = (SELECT DISTINCT obj.param1 from table1 WHERE...)
```

What I need is some kind of optimization, in order not to execute the inner SELECT query twice, once to do the count, once to retrieve the results needed in the parent SELECT query. Is this possible?

Comment: IMHO, no possible, you must change approach about your query

Comment: What database?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  MySql?

Comment: This is the only approach that comes to my mind, but any suggestion is appreciated. It does not have to be with SELECT CASE, but if it is optimized, I can live with it. @D Stanley, the database is Postgres

Comment: Why an empty string? Is it ok if it returns an empty set?

Comment: @adrianm I think it's ok, but any other attempt I made to optimize the query, I always got that the subquery returns more than one element, and that's the error that I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldnt you just do something like this instead and if no rows are returned then just detect that instead of returning an empty string or is this used as part of a bigger select statement?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 
WHERE obj2.param1 IN (
    SELECT obj1.param1 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE... 
    GROUP BY obj1.param1
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: The query is part of a bigger select statement, but initial results show that your piece of code is probably what I needed. Thanks.